# Military Symbols in Flex Viewer 2

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-flex-viewer, arcgis-military-analyst

1. I want to create Military Symbols in Flex Viewer 2. How I can accomplish it, including all the names and their code in an XML file and calling it within flex viewer is a pain. Is there any SDK available for this purpose. That can generate symbols for me with like MOLE provides.
2. If the SDK is available for JAVA or .NET, Please point it out, I will get an idea from it. I had heard about Defense Solution SDK and ARC Objects but want a bit guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your MXD and add military symbols as described in help topic [Adding Military Symbols to a Map](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Adding_military_features_to_a_map/000n00000008000000/). Publish the MXD (or MSD) to ArcGIS Server. Then add the MapServer or FeatureServer as a layer in your flex viewer. It will automatically pick up the symbols.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think my question was incomplete. Actually I want to allow users to draw MOLE Symbols on the run time. Not a published symbol. I will provide those symbols in widget, so that users can choose and draw from them.

Comment: Hmmm... Not sure how you could easily do that. There are thousands (possibly 10,000's) military symbols. Your best bet may be to build an Server Object Extension that navigates the military symbology database and returns search results to the end user.